# surf command in GNU octave

Tags: octave, gnu

I want to plot a 3D plane in GNU Octave using the surf command.

I have following data
e.g

```
a= [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17];

b= [ 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011];

c= [ -0.88 -8.87 -0.86 -0.82 -0.77 -0.71 -0.66 -0.62 -0.57 -0.54 -0.50 -0.47 -0.44 -0.42 -0.39 -0.377 -0.36 -0.89 -0.88 -0.85 -0.81 -0.76 -0.71 -0.66 -0.61 -0.57 -0.53 -0.50 -0.47 -0.44 -0.42 -0.39  -0.37 -0.36];
```

I could plot it using `plot3` command..

But how should I plot it by using `surf` command in GNU Octave?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do `surf(a,b,c)` then `c` must be a matrix of size `m x n` where `m` is the length of vector `a` and `n` the length of vector `b`. In your case, you could do something like:

```
cc = repmat(c,34,1);
surf(a,b,cc)
```

but I don't know if that's what you are expecting. Basically, for each value of `x` and `y`, you need a value of `z`.

Comment: It works fine. But now i am getting multiple points in z-axis (c). There should be one unique value of "c" for every combination of "a" and "b" in my plot.